# ArrayList won't store instance from user input

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I am trying to add an element to an ArrayList using user input. The problem is when I try add something and ask to list it, it doesn't show it in the list.

I thought it was a problem with the read method, but I am not sure if there is anything wrong with it. The other thing was the fact that the method for adding an element wasn't in a loop, I tried using a loop but it still wasn't working. 
There is a movie class with a constructor that has the parameters for `title`, `year`, `genre`, `price` and a toString method.

Expected result: After adding a movie, it should list the movie added.
Actual result: The add method asks for input but when I use the list method it doesn't list what I added.

Here is the full [Kiosk](https://codeshare.io/21Bx0n) and [Catalogue](https://codeshare.io/5gkD48) class for more context.

Comment: Where is your `moviesAvailable` variable defined? Its its a field of `Catalogue`, you have to realise you make 2 differend instances of your `Catalogue` class, and that means that they both have a differend state

Comment: You're listing the methods from a *new catalogue* - you should be listing the movies from the same catalog that you're adding to earlier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
new Catalogue().addMovie();
```

You are creating a new `Catalogue` each time you want to add a `Movie`, and you are never referencing it.

Instead, add all your movies to the same `Catalogue`:

```
private void addMovie(Catalogue c) {
    c.addMovie();
}

private void listMovie(Catalogue c) {
    c.listMovie();
}
```

Comment: I tried this but my code has text based menus too, the menu calls ```addMovie()``` and ```listMovie()```. I've added the full class code to the original post for more context.

Comment: @TDizzle Replace `new Catalogue().addMovie();` with `this.catalogue.addMovie();`, same for `listMovie()`. In your constructor `public Kiosk()`, add `this.catalogue = new Catalogue();`

Answer (score 0):

that's because of the 'new' keyword. you need to use singleton 'Catalogue' object here.

```
class Kiosk {
       private static Catalogue catalogue;

       public Catalogue getCatalogue() {
          if(Objects.isNull(catalogue)){
               catalogue = new Catalogue();
          }
          return catalogue; //will return singleton catalogue object
       }

       private void addMovie() {
          getCatalogue().addMovie();
       }

       private void listMovie() {
          getCatalogue().listMovie();
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kiosk you must keep an instance of your catalogue.
I don't know where you plan to create the Catalogue instance so added 2 constructors:

```
public class Kiosk {
    private Catalogue cat;

    public Kiosk() {
       this(new Catalogue());
    }
    public Kiosk(Catalogue catalogue) {
        this.cat=catalogue;
    }
    private void addMovie() {
        cat.addMovie();
    }

    private void listMovie() {
        cat.listMovie();
    }
}
```